# Deleting photo from Photos app doesn't delete from Finder

Tags: macos, photos, photos.app

When I delete photos from Photos app on my mac I would like to delete the photo from finder as well.

Is there a way to do this ?

Please see the file below still present in Finder after I deleted photos from Photos app and then emptying from 'Recently Deleted' folder as well

[image]

Comment: Where in Finder are you referring to? Have you emptied the Photos "Recently Deleted"?

Comment: Yes. I have emptied the 'Recently Deleted' from Photos app. But still the photo jpg file is present in finder. Basically, I want to delete unwanted photos from photos app and finder both. Deleting photos just from photos app and not from finder does not make sense since the unwanted file will eat up storage.

Comment: Can  you please confirm where you are seeing it in Finder?

Comment: I have added the picture from finder in the post. Please have a look. Hope its makes it easy to understand. Also I have imported the folder to photo app

Comment: For testing, I created a folder in finder which I imported into Photos app. This folder has one image file. When I deleted the image from photos, the file is still there in finder.

Answer (score 2):

I contacted Apple Support and this was their answer.

Resolution:

When you import an image from a folder in Finder, the [Photos app creates a copy of that file in its own library](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/190484/5472). So, now the Mac has two copies of the same image file.

So, ideally one should delete files from Finder after importing in the Photos app. Thereafter, images can be managed directly from the Photos app.

Answer (score 0):

When you import photo(s) into the Photos application, it creates a copy - it does not modify/reference the original.

You will have to manually delete the original photos after importing them.